Problem with Distribution Map Generator in QGIS
Using 3.22.4 Biatowieza and trying to use the 'Distribution Map Generator.  When I click OK it says will generate 1 map. continue?  I click yes and dialogue box appears "All layers must have the same projection".  However Base, Localities and Grid layers are all the same projection ie EPSG:3857 - WGS 84.  Why am I getting this error?
